# How to change Spring Profile between tests in order to repopulate an autowired component?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

How can I change the Spring profile between tests in order to repopulate the `@Component` `DatabaseEnabledTenants` with different values? Is that even possible?

I'd like to validate different behaviour based on `DatabaseEnabledTenants` containing different values.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DatabaseTenantsTest {

  @Autowired
  public DatabaseEnabledTenants databaseEnabledTenants;

  @Test
  public void test1() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(databaseEnabledTenants.getTenants());
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(databaseEnabledTenants.getTenants());
  }
}
```

`application-test.yml`:

```
multi-tenancy:
  tenants:
    "001":
      tenantId: "001"
    "002":
      tenantId: "002"
    "003":
      tenantId: "003"
```

`application-test2.yml`:

```
multi-tenancy:
  tenants:
    "001":
      tenantId: ""
    "002":
      tenantId: ""
    "003":
      tenantId: ""
```

`DatabaseEnabledTenants.java`:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "multi-tenancy")
public class DatabaseEnabledTenants {

  @NotNull private Map<String, String> tenants = new HashMap<>();

  public Map<String, String> getTenants() {
    return tenants;
  }

  public void setTenants(Map<String, String> tenants) {
    this.tenants = tenants;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to manually load spring context for each profile

Comment: only way i know is to split tests requiring different profiles to different classes, both with needed `@ActiveProfiles("xxx")` then if You run all project tests there will be two spring contexts